java 11 installation issue on oracle linux docker container
I am trying to install java 11 on oracle linux 9. using the below script for instalation.
#! /bin/bash

java_version=11.0.22.7.1

# Linux
os_arch=$(uname -s); os_arch_lower=$(echo "$os_arch" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'); echo "$os_arch_lower"

# architecture x86
os_arch=$(uname -i | cut -d'_' -f1 | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'); echo "$os_arch"

# Create the destination directory if it does not exist
mkdir -p /usr/java/

# Install Amazon correto jdk 11 
curl -LO https://corretto.aws/downloads/resources/${java_version}/amazon-corretto-${java_version}-${os_arch_lower}-${os_arch}.tar.gz \
&& mv "amazon-corretto-${java_version}-${os_arch_lower}-${os_arch}.tar.gz" "/usr/java/amazon-corretto-${java_version}-${os_arch_lower}-${os_arch}.tar.gz" \
&& cd /usr/java \
&& tar zxvf "amazon-corretto-${java_version}-${os_arch_lower}-${os_arch}.tar.gz" \
&& JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/amazon-corretto-${java_version}-${os_arch_lower}-${os_arch} \
&& export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/amazon-corretto-${java_version}-${os_arch_lower}-${os_arch} \
&& export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH \
&& echo $PATH \
&& java --version

even though after untarring the files to /usr/java/
i am getting error while running java command which means some issue with java installation.
bash.sh: line 23: /usr/java/amazon-corretto-11.0.22.7.1-linux-x86/bin/java: No such file or directory
please help me. what am i missing?
https://github.com/devwithkrishna/create-jenkins-docker-image/blob/main/download_install_amazon_correto.sh
i have tried to fix issue myself and with available solutions from google. but none of them worked.
even though it says it didnt find java file on error:
/usr/java/amazon-corretto-11.0.22.7.1-linux-x86/bin/java: No such file or directory
The file is present.
[root@83f38c9b634e /]$ ls -la /usr/java/amazon-corretto-11.0.22.7.1-linux-x86/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7436 Jan 10 19:48 /usr/java/amazon-corretto-11.0.22.7.1-linux-x86/bin/java


Aside: Instead of a && b && c && d && e && ..., consider a || exit as one command, b || exit as a second, etc -- considerably better readability that way, without the bugs introduced by set -e.

Anyhow -- use ldd to list the library dependencies of the file. Almost certainly one of them is missing.

(See bash claims executable file does not exist when trying to execute it but it does -- not that it's really a bash problem; the error comes from the OS kernel, not from the shell, and bash is just relaying it).

(Does Oracle not provide a properly packaged JVM for their own Linux distro, btw? That's some pretty serious WTF; when you install from your distro's package management tools rather than through a tarball, those package management tools become responsible for making sure all dependencies are present, avoiding the class of problem you're encountering here).

Oh. You're truncating the _64 from x86_64. Yeah, that won't work without going out of your way to install 32-bit libraries -- you really do have the exact same problem as the person whose question I linked in an above comment. x86 and x86_64 are not interchangeable.

i am just truncating it to get the proper url. see this is the download url https://corretto.aws/downloads/latest/amazon-corretto-11-x86-linux-jdk.tar.gz even if the architecture is x86_64bit, the download url only contains x86

Looking at Coretto's download page, they call x86_64 "x64". (That's a little confusing because that's a name that used to be used primarily to refer to Itanium). So just truncating you is taking you to the wrong page.
